# IE problem with html 5

Tags: internet-explorer, html

http://jsfiddle.net/naSmz/1/

The above link works fine with FF and Chrome, but IE 8 does not show properly the main content (#main). The content area becomes narrower.

I use a boiler template and 960grid for this.

I added htmlshiv.

Could anyone tell me what I need to do please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm comparing this in IE8 and Chrome and can't really see the big difference of the content area. Haven't measured it but it looks pretty much the same.

Comment: Is it possible boiler plate and 960grid are fighting each other somewhere? Does this validate?

Comment: can you post screenshots of what you are seeing?  I just compared in IE9 running in IE8 Standards mode (sorry, don't have IE8) and it looks pretty close to how it looks in C9 and FF4b11.  All 3 browsers render the content area with 960px width.  The fonts render differently for me across the browsers, but otherwise they look the same.

Answer (score 0):

For best results you should put your CSS just after the comment that says "Primary Styles".

Also, I am not sure why your right column has left and position defined, it is already a floated element.

You should also check our [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki/Get-Started!).